# How to get coordinate from geoserver

Tags: javascript, postgis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have this script.
I want to get coordinate from lokasi_penting,
and make it the centre of map.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#kirim2").click(function(){
                var x = document.getElementById('lokasi_penting2').value;   
var y = document.getElementById('jarak2').value;
            bintang_1 = new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            $.ajax('http://localhost:8383/geoserver/bagas/ows',{
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    service: 'WFS',
                    version: '1.0.0',
                    request: 'GetFeature',
                    typename: 'bagas:bintang_1',
                    srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                    outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
                    viewparams : "lokasi_penting:" + x +";jarak:" + y,
                    bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
                    },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback:'callback:loadFeaturesbin_1',
                jsonp:'format_options'
                });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
                maxZoom: 19
                })),
        });

        window.loadFeaturesbin_1 = function(response) {
        geoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        bintang_1.addFeatures(geoJSON.readFeatures(response));
        };
        var bin_1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: bintang_1,
        style: bintang_satu,
        name : 'bin_1'

        });
        map.addLayer(bin_1);
```

lokasi_penting and jarak are from geoserver. so I want to make coordinate from lokasi penting be a centre of my map after it loaded.

Comment: What is the question? All you provided was some code but no problem statement or question related to it

Comment: I want to take the coordinates of lokasi penting to be made a centre of map. cos, the centre of map is still default

Comment: that doesn't explain a problem or what is currently happening or not happening with code shown

Comment: Yes, the question is not really clear, but maybe you only need a  `map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x, y),10);`  ?

Comment: yes, that's it
but I need the coordinate from lokasi_penting coordinate. lokasi_penting is from geoserver.

Comment: Oh, you mean, the x and y variables in code are not the coordinates you need? I mean this line: `viewparams : "lokasi_penting:" + x +";jarak:" + y`. If not, I do not understand the question. The sentence `lokasi_penting is from geoserver` does not help. You can get coordinates from geoserver using WFS but you need to add much more details to you question. Is lokasi_penting a layer in Geoserver? Or is a feature contained in a layer? See here for more info about WFS: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html